# Gremlin : Alternative for otherV in CosmosDB Gremlin API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I don't want the same vertex to be traversed again, but I am not able to use otherV in CosmosDB Gremlin API. Is there an alternative for that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an example of your usage but sometimes I see folks do this:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).bothE().otherV() 
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
```

which is really just:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).both()
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
```

The latter is cheaper. You would only need `otherV()` in scenarios where you need to filter edges:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).bothE().has('weight',gt(0.4)).otherV() 
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
```

If you have this more legitimate situation where `otherV()` is needed you can implement a filter of your own with a step label and `where()` like:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).as('a').bothE().has('weight',gt(0.4)).union(inV(),outV()).where(neq('a'))
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
```